# get multipulate value from stored procedure

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this stored procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.getRegionsInArea
    (
    @areaID int,
    @ID int OUTPUT,
    @name varchar(50) OUTPUT
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT @ID = [ID], @name = [name] FROM Region
    WHERE areaID = @areaID
    END
```

I want to call it from `JDBC`.

#### questiong

how to get all the values of the variables outputs `ID` and `name` because the stored procedure returens many values of them.

#### what I tried

```
Connection con = Database.getConnection();
            String storedProcedure = "{call getRegionsInArea (?,?,?)}";
            CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
            try {
                callableStatement = con.prepareCall(storedProcedure);
                callableStatement.setInt(1, getID());
                callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2,
                        java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
                callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3,
                        java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
                callableStatement.execute();
                    System.out.println("ID = " + callableStatement.getInt(2));
                    System.out.println("name = "
                            + callableStatement.getString(3));
```

#### problem

I just receive the last value of `ID` and `name`.

any help please

Comment: Hi, Is there any issues with using callableStatement.getResultSet() or  callableStatement.executeQuery() and you can omit your output parameter for ID and Name and just return query result without storing it in some variables.

Comment: @VishalVaishya thanks for ur comment, I can user `getrestultset` but when i made this `restulsset.next()` i got null pointer exception on it

Comment: the same thing happened when i tried to use `executequery()`

Comment: Can you try with Cursor. Here is complete example. http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-cursor-example/

Comment: I will check it, but please is my stored procedure right?

Comment: Yes. Your SP is correct. I think the error is coz u must be missing callableStatement.execute() before u you use getResultSet(). Refer this link detailed example: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/tjvjdmlt.htm

Comment: I didn't miss that , it is impossible

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29085/discussion-between-vishal-vaishya-and-marco-dinatsoli)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this solution :

```
callableStatement = con.prepareCall(storedProcedure); 
callableStatement.setInt(1, getID()); 
callableStatement.execute(); 
ResultSet resultSet = callableStatement.getResultSet(); 
while (resultSet.next()) { 
   int returnedID = resultSet.getInt(1); 
   String returnedName = resultSet.getString(2);   
}
```

And alter your SP like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.getRegionsInArea 
( 
@areaID int
) 
AS 
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON 
SELECT [ID],[name] FROM Region 
WHERE areaID = @areaID 
END
```